# Flex 3 Value aware combo box error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, flex3

I am using a value aware combobox, it was working fine, but recently i started getting the below error, when I try to click on combobox, and the error is random.
I am not sure of it is because of any changes i have done in the coding, or some changes in data provider etc  any help is appreciated...

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/destroyDropdown()
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/styleChanged()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/setBorderColorForErrorString()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/commitProperties()
    at mx.controls::ComboBase/commitProperties()
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/commitProperties()
    at custom.controls::ComboBox/commitProperties()[D:\workspace\eclipse\indigo\ams\flex_src\custom\controls\ComboBox.mxml:13]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
```

Debugger throws

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/destroyDropdown()
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/styleChanged()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/setBorderColorForErrorString()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/commitProperties()
    at mx.controls::ComboBase/commitProperties()
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/commitProperties()
    at custom.controls::ComboBox/commitProperties()[D:\workspace\eclipse\indigo\ams\flex_src\custom\controls\ComboBox.mxml:13]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateNow()
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/displayDropdown()
    at mx.controls::ComboBox/downArrowButton_buttonDownHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.controls::Button/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::buttonPressed()
    at mx.controls::Button/mouseDownHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.controls::ComboBase/textInput_mouseEventHandler()
```

Here is the part of my code

```
[Bindable]
 private var networkExpObj:NetworkExpansion=new NetworkExpansion();
[Bindable]
 public var codeDescpResult:Object;
    <mx:FormItem label="Status"
                         required="true">
                <controls:ComboBox id="NWEXP_STATUS_ID"
                                   disabledColor="0x000000"
                                   maxWidth="150"
                                   change="validateUs()"
                                   selectedValue="{networkExpObj.NWEXP_STATUS_ID}"
                                   dataProvider="{codeDescpResult.SRV_NWE_STATUS}"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
```

Comment: What is a "value aware" Combobox? I don't think this is answerable wtihout the code that throws the error; so please provide it.

Comment: It is a custom combobox, please see this link[link]http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/11/22/Flex-ComboBox-With-selectedValue-Support  I am using this combobox and it was working fine for long time, recently, I end up with above error randomly.

Comment: Please share your code.  It looks like something is wrong w/ error related styles; but I'm just guessing from the stack trace.

Comment: I have hosted the file in this link [link]https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6jL_oXw1PpGNDFVQngyN1RNcjg, The error is not happening on any specific combobox, the screen has many combobox, the data provider for the combobox is coming for the parent. Sorry it is a big, file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code; do not host it externally.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed in Apache Flex 4.10 (not released yet) see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33382.

If using an older SDK you could monkey patch mx:ComboBox like so adding the "&& tween" check:

```
private function destroyDropdown():void
{
    if (inTween && tween)
        tween.endTween();

    displayDropdown(false, null, false);
}
```

Comment: Apache Flex 4.10 has been released.